# sendmail disabled

Tags: email, sendmail

My host has Sendmail() disabled. I'm basically looking for a way to bypass this. I want visitors to be able to send me (gmail account) an email where they first fill in their e-mail address, so they become the sender. It's for support questions and remarks.

If there is no way to bypass this, is there and alternative, perhaps using mailchimp..?

Comment: You can check this answer (note - there Pear is used):
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/712392/send-email-using-gmail-smtp-server-from-php-page

Comment: mail is not supported (due to abusive spamming (yeah right..)). So there is also no support for the mail package from PEAR.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use an alternative public send mail servers available. You can use one of them. Here is one [Public Send Mail server list](http://www.werockyourweb.com/list-outgoing-smtp-mail-servers)

Comment: I also forgot to mention that I have no access to php.ini, so I think setting up smpt would be impossible, am I right..?

Comment: you can use ini_set function, which will set it only for your application. http://us2.php.net/ini_set

Comment: mail is not supported (due to abusive spamming (yeah right..)). So I'm definitely not able to use the server's mail functions..

Comment: You can point to some public send mail server, to which the your PHP program would send the email request as php would see those server details and would use its sockets to connect to that server. In no way email would be sent by your localhost. For example, when you configure your outlook, do you have sendmail service on windows by default... Definitely no...! You point to a send mail server to which your PHP program would act as client(just like outlook).

Answer (score 0):

use phpmailer library. you can send email via connecting smtp (works with gmail too.) 1st configure one of your accounts with phpmailer. when the user fills in their email set the sender as user's email. 
even though you are actually sending the email through your account to receiver of the email will show as sent by user's email address.
http://phpmailer.worxware.com/